# Appium server is shut down because no new commands came in

Tags: android, ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, appium

I am using Appium for Android native app automation on windows machine. All my scenarios are doing good, but sometimes the App gets crashed and Appium stops saying "Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down".

Note - if explicitly i press any key from keyboard it will get next command to execute while cucumber execution.

I can see Appium is sending request to find the element, but no response has been received. I don't know why this is happening, but the same thing passes without any issue mostly. When this issue happens, Appium closes the app and the next coming scenarios also gets failed.

Someone help to resolve this issue.

This is the Appium server log:

> info: Starting App
>   info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
>   info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
>   info: [debug] executing cmd:                                            C:\Users\PG106\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 300450adeedc3100 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
>   info: [debug] No matching processes found
>   info: [debug] Running bootstrap
>   info: [debug] spawning: C:\Users\PG106\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 300450adeedc3100 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.paragyte.publicpartnerships.test -e disableAndroidWatchers false
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS:    id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS:                 class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
>   info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] json loading complete.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client:                      {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] executing cmd:    C:\Users\PG106\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 300450adeedc3100 shell "dumpsys window"
>
> info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result:                                      {"value":"/data/local/tmp","status":0}
>   info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue:                               ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client:       {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action:    compressedLayoutHierarchy
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":false,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd:  C:\Users\PG106\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 300450adeedc3100 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
>   info: [debug] executing cmd:   C:\Users\PG106\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 300450adeedc3100 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.paragyte.publicpartnerships.test/com.paragyte.publicpartnerships.SplashActivity"
>
> info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.paragyte.publicpartnerships.test" and activity "com.paragyte.publicpartnerships.SplashActivity" to be focused
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\PG106\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 300450adeedc3100 shell "dumpsys window windows"
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd:     C:\Users\PG106\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 300450adeedc3100 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
>
> info: [debug] Device is at release version 4.4.2
>   info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
>   info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
>   info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 16023.269 ms - 74
>   info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c {}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"","platformVersion":"4.4.2","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appiumVersion":"1.6.0","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.2","browserName":"","deviceName":"Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator","app":"D:\Automation\Mobile\apk_files/app-debug.apk","name":"Time 4 Care"},"appiumVersion":"1.6.0","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"300450adeedc3100","app":"D:\Automation\Mobile\apk_files/app-debug.apk","name":"Time 4 Care"},"sessionId":"00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c"}
>
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c 200 2.411 ms - 691 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"","platformVersion":"4.4.2","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appiumVersion":"1.6.0","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.2","browserName":"","deviceName":"Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator","app":"D:\Automation\Mobile\apk_files/app-debug.apk","name":"Time 4 Care"},"appiumVersion":"1.6.0","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"300450adeedc3100","app":"D:\Automation\Mobile\apk_files/app-debug.apk","name":"Time 4 Care"},"sessionId":"00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c"}
>
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}},"sessionId":"00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c"}
>
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 5.141 ms - 156 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}},"sessionId":"00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c"}
>
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c/timeouts/implicit_wait {"ms":0}
>   info: [debug] Set Android implicit wait to 0ms
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c"}
>
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c/timeouts/implicit_wait 200 2.471 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c"}
>
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c/appium/device/press_keycode {"keycode":93}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["pressKeyCode",{"keycode":93,"metastate":null}]
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"pressKeyCode","params":{"keycode":93,"metastate":null}}
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: pressKeyCode
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c/appium/device/press_keycode 200 258.139 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"00bd22a6-7f2e-435b-a6af-53f5bf115a2c"}
>
> info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...
>   info: Shutting down appium session
>   info: [debug] Pressing the HOME button
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd:              C:\Users\PG106\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 300450adeedc3100 shell "input keyevent 3"
>
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"OK, shutting down","status":0}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS:   id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 63.073
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   info: [debug] We shut down because no new commands came in

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: can you format your output? its too hard to read without the line breaks

Comment: I have formatted my output. it would be easy to read. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting your desired capability to a higher number? What is it currently set to?

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 10000);
```