# Appium: We shut down because no new commands came in

Tags: automation, appium

I'm running my code on appium 1.4.13 using java for android application.Also note that it was working perfectly before & suddenly sending such timeout response. Command time out limit is set to 300000000 secs. Let me know any more information is required to find a reason as i'm really stuck with this issue.

Here you go with a glimpse of an error which appium throws everytime,

```
info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 300000000 secs, shutting 
down...
info: [debug] Trying to stop appium but there's no session, doing 
nothing
info: [debug] We shut down because no new commands came in
```

Please note that i have already gone through below link but couldn't find any solution yet,
[Appium server is shut down because no new commands came in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242889/appium-server-is-shut-down-because-no-new-commands-came-in)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please try to use the latest version of Appium. There might be some issues with the older versions which may be causing this issue.

Timeout can be simply set as `capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 300);` Can you share the code that you have used to set the timeout. Because 300000000 seconds is ~9.5 years & it doesn't look like a good approach.

Comment: I retried with install-uninstall process of appium. Although before i was relaunching my application through appium, later on i tried with my code & shockingly it starts working now. I'm still not sure what helped me in this or it behaves randomly!

Comment: Great that you got it working!! Was it with the same version of Appium? Or the latest one?

Comment: Yeah, its with the same version.